# Javascript IDE which can locate parent object of method or property in the js code?

Tags: javascript, ide, intellij-idea, aptana

I have large Javascript files with objects containing many functions and properties which scroll through several pages and navigating the code is not easy.

I am looking for an IDE which when the caret is on a function, the IDE can help me locate its parent object.

I have looked at Aptana and IntelliJ Idea but can't find ways to do it.

Comment: I'm using the Aptana plugin for Eclipse and I push F3, while hovering over the call, to jump to a function declaration. Is that what you mean?

Comment: An object has a function like SendMail: function () {..}. I want to know which object has SendMail declared in it.

Answer (score 0):

try firebug
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28web_development%29

Comment: Please say how instead of just mentioning a product. I use Firebug, Google Chrome developer tools, Visual Studio 2010, Resharper, Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox, WebStorm and these all work with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, press the Ctrl key and move your mouse over the method call. You should see the mouse cursor change to a hand and a popup show the filename and the method declaration.

If you middle click on the method call you will be taken to the method declaration.